# Digest Authentication in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, digest-authentication

I am working on Meteor for prototype, where I am trying to ping an API server. The server requires digest-auth. I was able to do it in php and python with almost no issues, but it is proving more difficult in meteor.

I know that it won't be easy as digest-auth requires a challenge-response authentication also. Considering that Meteor does not have a production release can we do the authentication? Can I do it with some node.js package?

Any help or link to any online resource would be really helpful.

**EDIT 1:**
After using `request` as asked, how do I know that the request completed successfully?

```
var request = Npm.require('request');
var res = request.get('http://example.com/path/to/service', {
    'auth': {
        'user': 'username',
        'pass': 'password',
        'sendImmediately': false
    }
});
```

Comment: Check out the [NPM package](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm) for meteor and the [http-auth](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-auth) module for node.

Comment: @Cuberto I think the question is about making requests (as a client), not about enabling the meteor server to accept digest auth. does http-auth also enable requests with digest? Jehanzeb.Malik: please confirm.

Comment: @ChristianFritz No the API call would be running from server script. There is a background worker that needs to ping the server every 2 hours for updated information. The API after login gives a window of 3 mins to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the node [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request/) framework:

> Digest authentication is supported, but it only works with
>   `sendImmediately` set to `false`; otherwise `request` will send basic
>   authentication on the initial request, which will probably cause the
>   request to fail.

To include it in your meteor app use `Npm.require('request');`

Comment: I first tried to fetch google page to check if `request` was properly working. Once confirmed I tried digest auth as mentioned in documentation (code shown above in updated question "Edit 1"). How will I know that the request is successfully completed? There are no callbacks mentioned in the documentation.